# How to write a bash script that kills a python program running in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I need to write a simple bash script that kills a python script that is running in a terminal window. I'm assuming it will use `kill -PID` but I don't know how to get the PID of something based on what's running.

I'm sure this is elementary for someone experienced in bash scripts, but I am very new to the topic.

I appreciate all of your time, thanks so much!

Comment: Seems like the design of the Python script should be fixed instead?

Comment: @user535733 the python script is supposed to run continuously until a certain time, I need essentially a kill switch to shut it down no matter what the PID is, so I'm looking to make a bash script to do that

Comment: @PerlDuck after reading that question you mentioned, I figured out to have it tell me the PID and alot more, but I'm having trouble getting it to essentially `return PID` to put it in python terms.

Comment: Precisely. If running continuously, then it could be designed as a *service*, and supervised (started/stopped) by systemd along with all the other services. It's more complex up front to write and test, but easier to maintain across years.

Comment: @user535733 can you point me in the right direction as to how to make it a service and how to supervise it?

Comment: @PerlDuck never mind, just saw exactly what I need in that link. Thanks for the referral!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your script is named `test_script.py`. You can add an interpreter comment at the start of the script, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def function:
  #example function

#rest of script here
```

Then, execute chmod: `sudo chmod +x test_script.py`

And execute it like so: `./test_script.py`

Then to kill it, get the id of the script with the command: `pidof test_script.py`

And it will return the pid, kill it using `kill -9 [pid_here]`